# Запись связных сущностей Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, spring-jpa

пишу Rest Web-сервис, `Spring Boot+Hibernate+Postgres`, есть три сущности: класс А, В и А_В, ссылающийся на оба через `ManyToOne`, связь `onedirectional`. Надо записать А_В при этом автоматически создав А или В в одной транзакции. Это возможно вообще?

```
@Embeddable
class IdA {
String code; // code одинаков и для класса А, для В и для A_B
String nameA;
}
class A {
@EmbeddedId
IdA id;
}

@Embeddable
class IdB {
String code;
String nameB;
}
class B {
@EmbeddedId
IdB id;
}

@Embeddable
class IdA_B {
String code;
String nameA;
String name B;
LocalDate start;
}

class A_B {
@EmbeddedId
IdA_B id;

LocalDate end;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="code", referencedColumnName="code", insertable = false, updatable = false),
@JoinColumn(name="nameA", referencedColumnName="nameA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
A a;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="code", referencedColumnName="code", insertable = false, updatable = false),
@JoinColumn(name="nameB", referencedColumnName="nameB", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
B b;

}
```

И хочу записать инстанс класса А_В при условии что пока ни А ни В на которые он ссылается нет в БД.
Ну и сам метод

```
A a = new A(new IdA("code"," nameA"))
B b = new B(new IdB("code"," nameB"))
A_B ab = new A_B(new IdA_B("code", "nameA", "nameB", LocalDate.now()), LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), a, b);
abRepository.save(ab);
```

Comment: ... а Вы не могли бы описать сущность A_B?... что она из себя представляет и из чего она состоит...ну и если бы Вы хотя бы схематчески эти сущности проиллюстрировали то было бы проще. Что значит `Надо записать А_В при этом автоматически создав А или В в одной транзакции`?...Создать что?..таблицу...или экземпляр?... Не могу понять что Вам нужно и чем вызваны Ваши сложности...

Comment: Если вы используете спринг, то они создадутся в одной транзакции(если вы создаете их в одном методе помеченном как @Transactional)

Comment: @МихаилРебров  извиняюсь, дополнила вопрос

Comment: @aleshka-batman при попытке сохранить в методе помеченном `@Transactional` получаю `EntityNotFoundException`. P.S. дополнила вопрос

Comment: @Mircella ибо он пытается вставить ссылку на запись которой нет. Сначала надо вставить те две сущности, а потом загнать в `A_B`

Comment: @Tsyklop вот именно, а нет ли способа каскадом сохранить нужные мне сущности и сразу же за ними инстанс класса А_В?

Comment: @Mircella штука в том что тут много нюансов. Для связывания в таблице `A_B` используются `id` записей, но так как их нет то тут или уходить от такого вообще или делать эти поля просто цифрами, без привязки к `id` других таблиц. Но тут вытекают еще моменты. Как вы узнаете id этих записей, которые в будущем будут вставлены? а если в этот момент вставятся еще записи с таким же id?

Comment: @Mircella где-то изначально Вы что-то не так сделали ибо сиё не есть нормально.

Comment: @Tsyklop спасибо всем за участие, сама ж ответила на свой вопрос - каскад. Еще раз всем спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

`cascade(CascadeType.All)` - решило проблему.